# Porque el matches no me lo hace correctamente?

Tags: java

Lo he intentado de varias formas pero no consigo dar con la formula.
El ejercicio me pide esto:

¿Qué palabras son válidas para la sopa de letras? Deben empezar por una letra mayúscula y luego
contener letras minúsculas, como mínimo una. La ñ también es válida pero no los acentos. También
son válidas palabras compuestas. Ej: BaseDeDatos,AccesoADatos. Si la palabra no es válida, no se
coloca. Tampoco se coloca la palabra si el tamaño de la palabra es mayor que el tamaño de la matriz
o si no cabe en la posición y orientación indicadas.

```
public static boolean validarPalabra(String palabra) {
        return palabra.matches("[A-ZÑ][a-zñ]{1}[A-ZÑa-zñ].[a-zñ]");
        // "[A-ZÑ][a-zñ]{1}[A-ZÑa-zñ].[a-zñ]" con este matches Eva no vale, pero Juan
        // si
        // "[A-ZÑ][a-zñ]{1,}([A-ZÑ]{0,2}[a-z]{1,}){0,}[a-zñ]$"
        //"[A-ZÑ]{1}[[a-zñ]{1,}[A-ZÑ]{0,2}[a-zñ]${1,}]"
    }
```

Comment: Sera mucho más fácil si utilizas expresiones regulares para resolverlo

Comment: @solamente Eso intento, pero no consigo que me funcione al 100%, siempre hay un dato que me lo da como invalido

Comment: Ok le doy una vuelta ver si lo consigo yo y te mando un ejemplo

Comment: @solamente Muchas gracias, llevo varias pruebas hechas y no consigo dar con la solucion.

Comment: No he podido terminar te dejo hasta donde he llegado por si queires continuar (^[A-ZÑ])(?=.*[a-z])(?!àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝ)

Comment: @solamente eh?? pero que has hecho ahi?? jajajaja no entiendo muy bien que intentas hacer con **àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝ**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código debería solucionar tu problema. Los primeros corchetes dicen que has de introducir una mayúscula entre la "A" y la "Z" incluyendo la "Ñ", el segundo corchete dice que como mínimo, pero puede haber más, una letra de la "a" a la "z" incluyendo la "ñ" y el tercer corchete se abre a todas las letras de antes pero no obliga a poner un mínimo o un máximo:

```
public static boolean validarPalabra(String palabra) {
        return palabra.matches("[A-Z\u00D1]{1}[a-z\u00F1]+[A-Za-z\u00F1\u00D1]*");
    }
```

Añado otro código que creo sí cumple con todo lo que pides. Si no es así puede ser un buen punto de partida para que lo modifiques hasta conseguirlo:

```
public static boolean validarPalabra(String palabra) {
        return palabra.matches("([A-Z\u00D1]{1}[a-z\u00F1]+[A-Z\u00D1]{0,2}[a-z\u00F1]{1,})+([A-Z\u00D1]{0,2}[a-z\u00F1]+[A-Z\u00D1]{0,2}[a-z\u00F1]{1,})*");
    }
```

Comment: Por ejemplo la palabra: AccesoADatos deberia de entrar pero AccesoAD no puede entrar y AccesoADDatos tampoco porque tiene mas de 2 mayusculas

Comment: Entonces creo que no entiendo el requisito. Si "AccesoAD" no puede entrar porque tiene 2 mayúsculas ¿Por qué puede entrar "AccesoADatos"? ¿Puedes copiar el enunciado del ejercicio?

Comment: Porque debe de terminar en minuscula si o si y como maximo solo puede haber 2 mayusculas seguidas pero puede ser por ejemplo: AccESoADatos

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la respuesta con otro código que ya creo que sí hace lo que pides. Prueba a ver qué tal, @Aldione

Comment: Muchas gracias!! funciona